# What type of phrase is "at 9 pm"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles, argument-structure

> He sleeps at 9 pm.

What type of phrase is "at 9 pm" — adverbial or prepositional? What are the parts of speech of "9" and "pm" respectively?

Comment: This is not an idiomatic English sentence. "He goes to sleep at 9 pm" or "He is [already] sleeping/asleep at 9 pm".

Comment: The expression "at 9 pm" has the preposition "at" as head, so it it can only be a preposition phrase. Its function is that of temporal adjunct. Cardinal numbers are (mainly) determinatives, and the abbreviation "p.m." is probably best classified as a noun.

Comment: 9pm = noun + prepositional phrase. "9" is the name of a time; p.m. = post meridian = after (prep.) noon(n.) -- 9pm = noun phrase and the object of "at", thus creating an adverbial modifier.

Comment: "_Pm_" is the abbreviation of latin "_post meridiem_", not fully anglicised and considered in the SOED as either an adjective or an adverbial phrase; here it is an adverbial phrase.

Comment: @Greybeard cardinal numbers are determinatives, not nouns, so 9pm can hardly be an NP can it?

Comment: @LPH If p.m. is an adverb how can it post-modify the determinative "9".

Comment: @BillJ In "9 precisely", there is no doubt that "precisely" is an adverb; doesn't it modify "9"? Wouldn't then be "pm" having the same function?

Answer (score 2):

To essentially repeat what Kate said earlier, while "at 9 p.m." is a prepositional phrase, the sentence given is not correct English. "At 9 p.m." needs to refer to specific event taking place at that time (e.g. "The night club opens at 9 p.m.").

Comment: You would write: "He sleeps at night" (period of time) or "He goes to sleep at 9 pm" (brief action happening at a specific time) or "He is sleeping at 9 pm" (continuing action at particular time).

Answer (score -1):

This is indeed correct English. When it comes to verb usage, prepositional phrases function the same as a direct object. The verb used here, "to sleep," is used transitively. That is, the prepositional phrase is used as a direct object to the verb.

Comment: This "answer" is pure nonsense: NP ≠ PP! A prepositional phrase can only ever be a modifier, never a core argument to the verb, whether subject or object.  Even worse is the heresy that *sleep* is transitive, particularly here. Next time you really need to sleep that baby to somebody else before you send her out so unprepared into the world. Plus it's not correct in the first place.